# How do I solve SQL Error: ORA-00904: "NUMER_OF_ITEMS": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I'm trying to use an insert statement and a select to insert data into a table, but I keep getting an invalid identifier error.

```
INSERT INTO Customers_Statistics
SELECT count(*), sum(numer_of_items) 
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN Orders o on o.Order_id = o.Order_id GROUP BY c.Customer_id;
```

Error message:
`SQL Error: ORA-00904: "NUMER_OF_ITEMS": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`

Comment: Perhaps you want `number_of_items`.  Seems unlikely that a table is created with a spelling error in the column names.

Comment: I fixed the spelling error, but now it says number_of_items is an invalid identifier @GordonLinoff

Comment: @ClementOkereke - we don't know  anything about your tables. Check the columns you are referring to actually exist in those tables. If you still can't see the problem then add the table DDL or descriptions to your question. (It's also a good idea to prefix a column reference with the alias of the table it comes from, and to include the target table column names in the insert; though those aren't the issue here.)

Comment: In [old 9.2 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm) it is clearly described: *Cause: The column name entered is either missing or invalid.* So you should use valid identifier, which we cannot know without DDL for the tables.

Comment: Is `num[b]er_of_items` a column in one of the two tables you are joining? You can run `describe customers` and `describe orders` to find out. Separate from that, your join condition is almost surely wrong (even though it will not throw an error); you are comparing `o.order_id` to itself. Not sure what the correct thing is to join on (a `customer` table shouldn't have an `order_id` column), but what you do have makes no sense.